# Access bits in memory

Tags: c++

I want to assemble a message bit by bit, then handle the message as a vector of unsigned characters ( e.g. to calculate the CRC )

I can assemble the message OK, using either a `std::vector<bool>` or a `std::bitset`

I can copy the assembled message to a std::vector doing it **bit by bit**.  ( Note: the meesage is padded so that its length is an integer number of bytes  )

```
// assemble message
std::vector<bool> bitMessage;
...

// copy the bits one by one into bytes and add them to the message
std::vector<unsigned char> myMessage;

// loop over bytes
for (int kbyte = 0;
     kbyte < bitMessage.size() / 8;
     kbyte++)
{
    unsigned char byte = 0;

    // loop over bits
    for (int kbit = 0;
         kbit < 8;
         kbit++)
    {
        // add bit to byte
        byte += bitMessage[8 * kbyte + kbit] << kbit;
    }

    // add byte to message
    myMessage.push_back(byte);
}
```

This works.

But it seems awfully slow!  I would like to use `std::memcpy`.

For a 'normal' vector I would do

```
memcpy(
  myMessage.data(),
  bitMessage.data(),
  bitMessage.size() / 8 );
```

or

```
memcpy(
  &myMessage[0],
  &bitMessage[0],
  bitMessage.size() / 8 );
```

but neither of these methods is possible with either a `vector<bool>` or `bitset`

**Question:** **Is there a way to get a pointer to the memory where the bits are stored?**

---

The answer is: not with `std::vector<bool>` or `std::bitset`

However, with some hints , especially from @Ayxan Haqverdili, it is possible to write a small class that will accept single bits and construct a well mannered `std::vector<unsigned char>` as we go along.

```
/** Build a message bit by bit, creating an unsigned character vector of integer length
 * 
 * Hides the messy bit twiddling required,
 * allowing bits to be added to the end of the message
 * 
 * The message is automatically padded at the end with zeroes
 */
class cTwiddle
{
public:
    std::vector<unsigned char> myMessage;

    cTwiddle() : myBitLength(0) {}

    /** add a bit to end of message
     * @param[in] bit 
     */
    void add(bool bit)
    {
        // check if message vector is full
        if (!(myBitLength % 8))
        {
            // add byte to end of message
            myMessage.push_back(0);
        }
        
        // control order bits are added to a byte
        int shift = 7 - (myBitLength % 8);  // add bits from left to right ( MSB first )
        // int shift = (myBitLength % 8);  // add bits from right to left ( LSB first )

        myMessage.back() += (1 & bit) << shift;
        myBitLength++;
    }

private:
    int myBitLength;
};
```

Comment: Define "awfully slow".

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @nicomp Just for you, I have added my question explicitely.

Comment: why dont you use a `std::vector<unsigned char>` from the start? I dont understand what purpose the `std::vector<bool>` serves you (other than bringing complications)

Comment: Depending on your use case, [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) might be a better representation than `unsigned char`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  I need to assemble the message one bit at a time.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, the OP probably does not know about the weird behaviour of `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him if they weren't there would be no question...

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him  I do know.  That is why I am looking for another approach

Comment: @Eljay I have a lot of code that manipulates vector<unsigned char>  I want to avoid rewriting all that for this special case.

Comment: you want to benefit from the dense packing of `std::vector<bool>` ? If thats not necessary you could use a vector of a struct with a `bool` member

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number.  It is necessary.  For example, the standard NIC hardware expects a dense packed chunk of memory full of bits.

Comment: i don't know how it is typically implemented, but note that one of the peculiarities of [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is that it does not necessarily store the elements in contiguous memory

Comment: @ravenspoint -- It is implementation defined as to how `std::vector<bool>` stores values.  Maybe you should roll your own, or get a library that actually does what you want in the manner you want.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  I am aware of that.  That is why I am asking this question.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  If I knew how to roll my own or if I knew of such a library, then I would not be asking this question, would I?

Comment: @ravenspoint *If I knew how to roll my own* -- The Amazing Kreskin I am not. I have no idea if you could or could not.  I made the comment assuming you could, and you're simply trying standard C++ solutions first.

Comment: @ravenspoint How are you getting this data in the first place?  Putting it into a `vector<unsigned char>` right then might be your easiest option.

Comment: sorry, then I don't understand the question. You want to get a pointer to an array, but you already know that this array does not (necesarily) exist.

Comment: @NathanOliver  Placing single bits into unsigned characters requires a lot of masking and bit shifting which makes the message assembly code obscure and hard to ckeck that the requirements have been correctly implemented.  For me, code readability is vital for long term maintenance.

Comment: Use a `std::bitset` for that.  You can have a `bitset<8>` that you assemble the 8 bits of an unsigned char together, and then use its `to_ulong` function to convert the bitset into an integer you can store in the `vector<unsigned char>`

Comment: @NathanOliver  Finally, an interesting suggestion.  I am using bitset as an alternative to the code I posted, set to the full length of the message and then copied bit by bit to the unsigned char message.  You are suggesting doing it one byte at a time?  At first glance, that would be even slower and require mode lines of code, with setting bits and copying bytes all mixed together.

Comment: A vector of bytes or whatever the biggest integer type you can support, along with a counter to indicate which bit you're on is all you need.

Comment: @ravenspoint. You're writing C++, but you say " Placing single bits into unsigned characters requires a lot of masking and bit shifting which makes the message assembly code obscure and hard to ckeck that the requirements have been correctly implemented. For me, code readability is vital for long term maintenance.". Perhaps "made up" is incorrect, but "non-sequitur" or "inconsistent" would be a more polite phrasing? You're giving a reason for not doing bit-twiddling that makes no sense (to me, with my limited context).

Comment: If you have an accumulator byte and a bit coming in, it's a single shift followed by or. You could use `&1` first if you're not sure it's a single bit...

Comment: @ravenspoint Is there any gain if you unroll the inner loop (loop over bits)? If that's the case I can provide an implementation that also leverages Duff's device, to emulate `memcpy` and check if aiding vectorization is of any use here (it would be interesting to find out). Alternatively boost's dynamic bitset is almost always better that `vector<bool>` but if I'm assuming you cannot use it (?)

Comment: Also it's worth doing `myMessage.reserve(bitMessage.size() / 8)` prior to pushing back since you already know the resulting message size and it's best to avoid the reallocations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently neither of those classes define the layout. Just write your own class and define the layout you want:

```
template <int size>
class BitSet final {
 private:
  unsigned char buffer[size / 8 + (size % 8 != 0)] = {};

 public:
  constexpr bool get(size_t index) const noexcept {
    return (buffer[index / 8] >> (index % 8)) & 1U;
  }

  constexpr void set(size_t index) noexcept {
    buffer[index / 8] |= (1U << (index % 8));
  }

  constexpr void clear(size_t index) noexcept {
    buffer[index / 8] &= ~(1U << (index % 8));
  }
};
```

Memcpy-ing this class is perfectly fine. Otherwise, you might also provide direct access to the byte array.

Alternatively, you can dynamically allocate the buffer:

```
#include <memory>

class DynBitSet final {
 private:
  size_t size = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> buffer;

 public:
  explicit DynBitSet(size_t bitsize)
      : size(bitsize / 8 + (bitsize % 8 != 0)),
        buffer(new unsigned char[size]{}) {}

  bool get(size_t index) const noexcept {
    return (buffer[index / 8] >> (index % 8)) & 1U;
  }

  void set(size_t index) noexcept { buffer[index / 8] |= (1U << (index % 8)); }

  void clear(size_t index) noexcept {
    buffer[index / 8] &= ~(1U << (index % 8));
  }

  auto bitSize() const noexcept { return size * 8; }
  auto byteSize() const noexcept { return size; }
  auto const* byteBuffer() const noexcept { return buffer.get(); }
};
```

Comment: @Eljay Apparently not. Thankfully creating a bitset is not that difficult.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you for pointing out. I removed that example.

Comment: This looks interesting.  The message is always padded to an integer byte length,  So just throw an exception if size is not a multiple of 8

Comment: @ravenspoint Since the size is a compile-time value, you can use `static_assert` instead of throwing an exception, which is much nicer.

Comment: This assumes the `size` is known at compile type.  If size isn't known at compile time and needs to be dynamic, the backing store of BitSet can be a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.  The big value-add of BitSet is encapsulating all the fussy bit twiddling implementation details.

Comment: @Eljay yes, the size can be turned into a runtime-value without much trouble. Then you would memcpy the buffer of the vector, which is also fine.

Comment: Looks like I will accept this answer.  Will have to integrate it with my code, but right now I need a break - this has been intense!  If possible, edit it to show details of dynamic size implementation

Comment: @ravenspoint I added an example implementation for that as well.

Comment: Thanks.  What does the final in `class DynBitSet final` do?

Comment: @ravenspoint It means no classes can derive from this class. It is not essential, you can leave it out. I did that because this class is not designed to be derived from.

Comment: Thank you.  This answer pushed me in the right direction to write a class that does exactly what I need and no more.  My class is appended to my post

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get a pointer to the memory where the bits are stored [in std::vector]?

No. The idea is that it should be not possible.

> Is there a way

Fun fact: In glibc the member in iterator is public.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::vector<bool> vec{1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1};
    std::cout << *vec.begin()._M_p << '\n';
}
```